# Syntaxic analysis and parser

Tags: java, parsing, analytic-functions, jflex

I want to parse something like that :

path.to.variable

"path" and "to" are object named "Instance" and variable reference a double.

I've got the following grammar :

```
expr                ::= instancePath:i INSTANCE_SEPARATOR SHORTCUT:s
                    {:
                        RESULT = getDouble(s);
                    :}
                ;



instancePath        ::= instanceSubPath:p
                    {:
                        RESULT = p;
                    :}
                ;


instanceSubPath     ::= instanceSubPath:i1 INSTANCE_SEPARATOR instanceSubPath:i2
                    {:
                        RESULT = i2;
                    :}
                | SHORTCUT:s
                    {:
                        RESULT = pushInstance(s);
                    :}
                ;
```

In this grammar :

- INSTANCE_SEPARATOR is the "." char.
- SHORTCUT is a named with only letters like "path", "to" or "variable".
- expr must return a double value obtained by the call of the function getDouble which takes a name (here "variable"). This function use the current selected instance. An instance contains a hashtable which contains double or other instance.
- pushInstance is a function which set the current instance

for example we could have :

- an instance "path" which contains a hashtable which is : "to"=>link to instance "to"
- an instance "to" which contains a hashtable which is : "variable"=>10
- the path "path.to.variable" must return 10.

This does not run because the grammar complains a null value. This is due to the fact the parser does this :

```
expr(
  instancePath(
    instanceSubPath(SHORTCUT("path"))
    INSTANCE_SEPARATOR 
    instanceSubPath(SHORTCUT("to")) 
    INSTANCE_SEPARATOR 
    instanceSubPath(SHORTCUT("variable"))
  )
  INSTANCE_SEPARATOR
  !NULL!
```

)

instead of doing

```
expr(
 instancePath(
    instanceSubPath(SHORTCUT("path"))
    INSTANCE_SEPARATOR 
    instanceSubPath(SHORTCUT("to")) 
 )
 INSTANCE_SEPARATOR 
 SHORTCUT("variable")
)
```

Why ? is there precedence problems ?

To finish, if I remove the instancePath rule, all runs :

```
expr                ::= instanceSubPath:i INSTANCE_SEPARATOR SHORTCUT:s
                    {:
                        RESULT = getDouble(s);
                    :}
                ;


instanceSubPath     ::= instanceSubPath:i1 INSTANCE_SEPARATOR instanceSubPath:i2
                    {:
                        RESULT = i2;
                    :}
                | SHORTCUT:s
                    {:
                        RESULT = pushInstance(s);
                    :}
                ;
```

I can't remove this extra rules because I've simplified the example but it's quite more complex in reality.

I don't understand why deleting this extra rule solve my problem...

Comment: You probably need to tell us which parser generator you are using.

Comment: this is java cup for parser and jflex for lexer